# Where does the request in arguments come from?

Tags: python, api, flask, oauth

This might be very basic question I guess and I just started to learn API. I would like to know what actually is request in `return auth.auth_execute(request)`. 
This code is a slight part of API module I'm reading and I tried to find the definition of request in other files and modules but I could not find it anywhere even in `auth_execute()`. What data actually is in request ? Where does it come from ?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
import logging    

from .url.authentication import authentication as auth

@app.route("/v1/oauth/token", methods=['POST'])
   def authentication():

   return auth.auth_execute(request)
```

Comment: Are you asking what happens on the wire when you send that request?  Open up Fiddler or some other diagnostic HTTP proxy to observe the data sent/received on the wire.

Comment: See the documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#accessing-request-data

Comment: you may want to correct indentation for `def authentication()`

Comment: probably `dir(request)` is useful

Comment: Seeing as the only request type that this function accepts is `POST`, it likely contains some value from the client-side. In the function, print `request` and go from there!

Comment: @AdamMitchell This is what I really wanted to know. I tried to use curl command with POST method on local but I failed and was trying to identify the request. In this case, the request receives what I send with curl command, and the  API works based on what I send by curl. Is this correct understanding ?

Comment: @Amy Thank you for comments. I was just curious of more basic point rather than that.

Comment: @KlausD. Iv already read it out many times but thank you.

Comment: @akshat Thank you for the comment but this was not what I wanted know. Sorry for my poor details on the above.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak I’m going to use it sometime.